# Get all Items sold based on a collection of Items from a master table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have an Item Table where all transactions are stored by different site location and business date, I also have a key for each order stored.My item table structure is as below:

**Item Table**

```
SiteID   BusinessDate   ItemName   Units Sold   Units Sale   ItemNo  OrderNo
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1        06/08/2018     Apple         1             5        10001    122-1
1        06/08/2018     Coffee        1             16       10002    122-1
1        06/08/2018     Bread         2             7        10003    122-1
1        06/08/2018     Beans         9             18       10004    122-1

1        06/08/2018     Apple         2             5        10001    122-4
1        06/08/2018     Coffee        2             6        10002    122-4
1        06/08/2018     Bread         1             7        10003    122-4
1        06/08/2018     Beans         4             8        10004    122-4

2        06/08/2018     Apple         2             5        10001    122-2
2        06/08/2018     Coffee        1             6        10002    122-2

3        06/08/2018     Bread         3             5        10003    122-3
3        06/08/2018     Beans         7             17       10004    122-3
```

also, my master menu items table structure is as below:

**Item Master**

```
ItemNo      Name      Category 
---------------------------------
10001       Apple     C1    
10002       Coffee    C1  
10003       Bread     C2   
10004       Beans     C2
```

**Expected Results:**
I want to Generate the following output:

```
ItemNo      Name      C1      C2 
---------------------------------
10001       Apple     5       3
10002       Coffee    4       3
10003       Bread     3       6
10004       Beans     13      20
```

In the above output, basically we are checking each items from the master table against each category set defined within it.

The values under column C1 are the actual units sold that went together with  Apple or Coffee after checking all the records order by order in my Item table.

We are taking one base item such as Apple from Master table and checking in our Item table what was sold with apple under category C1. 
**Example:**
how many items of Bread was sold together with either coffee or apple?

Comment: I can clearly see where you get a value of 5 in the C1 column for Apple, but I am a little fuzzy on how you calculate 3 for C2.

Comment: @JM_, the value of 3 came as I need to get the value of Units Sold for apple that went along with either Bread or Beans after checking each order.

Comment: @Omran . .  Your comment does not help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have updated my question with clear requirements :)

Comment: @Omran . . . I still don't get what "C2" refers to as a column header.  "Apple" is not in category C2.  I don't get what numbers are being added up.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, C2 is the category name coming from master table. and here we are checking all the itemNos from C2 that was sold along with Apple.

Comment: @Omran . . . Which I calculate as "17".

Comment: @GordonLinoff that's also correct result, if you're counting the items sold with apple not the apple itself that came 3 times with the matching items

Answer (score 1):

This will probably get you most of the way there.  I did not put in logic to move the summary columns around as that would only work for two categories, and I assume you have many more.

```
CREATE TABLE #Master(ItemNo int,[Name] varchar(50), Category varchar(5)) 
INSERT INTO #Master VALUES(10001,'Apple','C1' )   
INSERT INTO #Master VALUES(10002, 'Coffee' ,'C1')  
INSERT INTO #Master VALUES(10003,'Bread','C2')   
INSERT INTO #Master VALUES(10004,'Beans' ,'C2')  

CREATe TABLE #Transactions(SiteID int,BusinessDate date,ItemName varchar(50),[Units Sold]int,[Units Sale]int,ItemNo int,  OrderNo varchar(20))
INSERT INTO #Transactions VALUES(1,'06/08/2018','Apple',1,5,10001,'122-1')
INSERT INTO #Transactions VALUES(1,'06/08/2018','Coffee',1,16,10002,'122-1')
INSERT INTO #Transactions VALUES(1,'06/08/2018','Bread',2,7,10003,'122-1')
INSERT INTO #Transactions VALUES(1,'06/08/2018','Beans',9,18,10004,'122-1')
INSERT INTO #Transactions VALUES(1,'06/08/2018','Apple',2,5,10001,'122-4')
INSERT INTO #Transactions VALUES(1,'06/08/2018','Coffee',2,6,10002,'122-4')
INSERT INTO #Transactions VALUES(1,'06/08/2018','Bread',1,7,10003,'122-4')
INSERT INTO #Transactions VALUES(1,'06/08/2018','Beans',4,8,10004,'122-4')
INSERT INTO #Transactions VALUES(2,'06/08/2018','Apple',2,5,10001,'122-2')
INSERT INTO #Transactions VALUES(2,'06/08/2018','Coffee',1,6,10002,'122-2')
INSERT INTO #Transactions VALUES(3,'06/08/2018','Bread',3,5,10003,'122-3')
INSERT INTO #Transactions VALUES(3,'06/08/2018','Beans',7,17,10004,'122-3')


;WITH CTE AS (
select MS.ItemNo,MS.Name,MS.Category, SUM(TR.[Units Sold]) RootItemSold, tr.OrderNo
from #Master MS
INNER JOIN #Transactions TR on MS.ItemNo = TR.ItemNo
GROUP BY MS.ItemNo,MS.Name,MS.Category, tr.OrderNo
),
MiddleCalc as
(
select ItemNo, [Name],Category,RootItemSold,OrderNo
,(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(1),0)  FROM CTE T2 where TRoot.OrderNo = t2.OrderNo and TRoot.Category <> t2.Category) HasOtherCategory
from CTE TRoot
)
SELECT ItemNo,[Name],[Category], 
CASE WHEN Category = 'C1' THEN
        SUM(RootItemSold)  
    ELSE
        SUM(CASE WHEN HasOtherCategory <> 0 THEN RootItemSold ELSE 0 END)  END C1,
CASE WHEN Category = 'C2' THEN
        SUM(RootItemSold)  
    ELSE
        SUM(CASE WHEN HasOtherCategory <> 0 THEN RootItemSold ELSE 0 END)  END C2
FROM MiddleCalc
GROUP BY ItemNo,[Name],[Category]
```

Comment: Hi @JM_, the output query shows the total units sold of bread = 6 whereas i want to get the total bread sold with category C1 which are either apple or coffee

Comment: The output of that query gives the exact result you asked for with the exception that I did not create separate columns for C1 and C2 because it would be unscalable if you had more that 2 categories. Hopefully that makes sense

Comment: Hi @JM_ thank you really for the help, But will it be possible to fix it for both columns C1 & C2 only as i don't need to scale it further

Comment: Sure, you would just put a case statement in to determine which sum you put in which column based on category.

Comment: Hi @JM_  will it be possible to help me with it if you don't mind?

Comment: Sure but it won't be until later

Comment: Updated as requested

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ItemNo,COUNT(items.Category) AS caategoryCOUNT,ItemName   FROM items 
INNER JOIN master_items ON items.ItemNo = master_items.ItemNo  
GROUP BY Category;
```

Comment: Your syntax has a lot issue, I don't think it will give me the desired result.

Comment: I updated the answer once again check.. Can you please be clear of what you need archieve?

Comment: for each item within my master table, i want to get all the units sold along with each category set. for instance the value of 3 came in C2 column for apple product  as I need to get the value of Units Sold for apple that went along with either Bread or Beans after checking each order.