# Retrieve all the orders that was sold together with group of items

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the below tables

**Order Table**:

```
SiteID   BusinessDate   ItemName   Units Sold   Units Sale   ItemNo  OrderNo
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1        16/08/2018     Apple         1             5        10001    122-1
1        16/08/2018     Beans         9             18       10004    122-1

1        16/08/2018     Apple         2             5        10001    122-4
1        16/08/2018     Coffee        2             6        10002    122-4
1        16/08/2018     Beans         4             8        10004    122-4

2        16/08/2018     Apple         2             5        10001    122-2
2        16/08/2018     Coffee        1             6        10002    122-2

3        16/08/2018     Bread         3             5        10003    122-3
3        16/08/2018     Beans         7             17       10004    122-3
```

**Menu Master Table**

```
ItemNo    Full Name   Menu Category 
---------------------------------
10001       Apple     Group1    
10002       Coffee    Group1  
10003       Bread     Group2   
10004       Beans     Group2   
10005       Orange    Group3
```

Based on the above tables, I want to get all the orders details that was sold under Group 1 items together with Group 2?

**RESULT**

```
SiteID   BusinessDate   ItemName   Units Sold   Units Sale   ItemNo  OrderNo
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1        16/08/2018     Apple         1             5        10001    122-1
1        16/08/2018     Beans         9             18       10004    122-1

1        16/08/2018     Apple         2             5        10001    122-4
1        16/08/2018     Coffee        2             6        10002    122-4
1        16/08/2018     Beans         4             8        10004    122-4
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all Items sold based on a collection of Items from a master table in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58890326/get-all-items-sold-based-on-a-collection-of-items-from-a-master-table-in-sql-ser)

Answer (score 0):

If you want all orders with both groups, then one method uses `join`, `group by`, and `having`:

```
select o.orderno
from orders o join
     itemmaster im
     on o.itemno = im.itemno
group by o.orderno
having sum(case when im.category = 'Group1' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when im.category = 'Group2' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

If you want the detailed lines for the orders, use correlated subqueries:

```
select o.*
from orders o
where exists (select 1
              from itemmaster im
              where o.itemno = im.itemno and im.category = 'Group1'
             ) and
      exists (select 1
              from itemmaster im
              where o.itemno = im.itemno and im.category = 'Group2'
             );
```

Comment: I tried the first query and it shows the order no only but the second query doesn't return any value

Comment: @annoynmous  . . . Ten the first query should answer your question.  It is not clear why the second query would not return the rows associated with the same orders.

Comment: the first query works where i get only order nos but the second query return zero output.

Answer (score 0):

Join the tables, group by orderno and set the condition in the `having` clause:

```
select o.orderno
from [Order] o inner join [Menu Master] m
on m.itemno = o.itemno
where m.[Menu category] in ('Group1', 'Group2')
group by o.orderno
having count(distinct m.[Menu category]) = 2
```

If you want all the details from `[Order]`:

```
select * from [Order]
where orderno in (
    select o.orderno
    from [Order] o inner join [Menu Master] m
    on m.itemno = o.itemno
    where m.[Menu category] in ('Group1', 'Group2')
    group by o.orderno
    having count(distinct m.[Menu category]) = 2
)
```

Comment: does it check for ItemNo 10001 and see if there're any order that was sold along with either Bread or Beans if yes bring me the entire order if no don't show it. similarly if ItemNo 10002 then if there're any order that was sold along with either Bread or Beans if yes bring me the entire order if no don't show

Comment: The subquery after IN, returns all the itemnos that meet the condition. Did you try it?

Comment: yup I did try it but am testing it more, what does having count(distinct m.[Menu category]) = 2 means here? if i have more category i should increment it?

Comment: 2 is the number of items inside the IN clause. If you query for ('Group1', 'Group2', 'Group3') then change it to 3.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get all the orders details that was sold under Group 1 items together with Group 2

I might be misunderstanding,  but it sounds like you need a simple `JOIN` between the Order Table and Menu Master Table on `ItemNo` with a filter on `[Menu Master Table].[Menu Category]`.  Since you aren't asking that it be grouped by `orderno` below, is what I assume you're looking for (NOTE:  there weren't actually any orders that contained Group3 in your order table example so this result is exactly what the order table looks like in your question):

```
SiteID   BusinessDate   ItemName   Units Sold   Units Sale   ItemNo  OrderNo
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1        16/08/2018     Apple         1             5        10001    122-1
1        16/08/2018     Beans         9             18       10004    122-1
1        16/08/2018     Apple         2             5        10001    122-4
1        16/08/2018     Coffee        2             6        10002    122-4
1        16/08/2018     Beans         4             8        10004    122-4
2        16/08/2018     Apple         2             5        10001    122-2
2        16/08/2018     Coffee        1             6        10002    122-2
3        16/08/2018     Bread         3             5        10003    122-3
3        16/08/2018     Beans         7             17       10004    122-3
```

```
SELECT SiteID, BusinessDate, ItemName, [Units Sold], [Units Sale], o.ItemNo, OrderNo
FROM Orders o
JOIN MenuMaster m ON o.ItemNo = m.ItemNo
WHERE m.[Menu Category] IN ('Group1', 'Group2')
```

This is basically what @forpas wrote but he added the group by which didn't make sense to me based on your question, but perhaps you needed that part.

**UPDATE**
The expected results helps.

I normally use `#temp` tables for stuff like this instead of inline sub-queries.  It's just easier to conceptualize for me.  There is probably a more 'elegant' way to do this, but the following would work.

Find order numbers that have Group 1 in them and put them into a temp table.  Then among those orders, find the order numbers that have group 2 and put those into a final temp table.  Then join Order table to that second temp table:

```
SELECT o.OrderNo
INTO #GroupOneOrders
FROM Orders o
JOIN MenuMaster m on o.ItemNo = m.ItemNo
WHERE m.MenuCategory = 'Group1'
GROUP BY o.OrderNo

SELECT o.OrderNo
INTO OrdersWithGroupOneAndTwo
FROM Orders o
JOIN #GroupOneOrders g1 on o.OrderNo = g1.OrderNo
WHERE EXISTS 
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM Orders o2
    JOIN MenuMaster m on o.ItemNo = m.ItemNo
    WHERE o2.OrderNo = o.OrderNo
        AND m.MenuCategory = 'Group2'
)

SELECT o.SiteID, o.BusinessDate, o.ItemName, o.UnitsSold, o.UnitsSale, o.ItemNo, o.OrderNo
FROM Orders o
JOIN #OrdersWithGroupOneAndTwo g ON o.OrderNo = g.OrderNo
```

Comment: Please see my exptected results, the above query will not help me here as I want to check for ItemNo 10001 and see if there're any order that was sold along with either Bread or Beans if yes bring me the entire order if no don't show it. similarly if ItemNo 10002 then if there're any order that was sold along with either Bread or Beans if yes bring me the entire order if no don't show

Comment: That makes more sense.  The initial question could be read a couple of different ways.  I update it with a different solution.